# How to make a for loop to apply conditional formating?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, reference

I created a conditional formatting for the first set of columns `(C:E)` (see image 3).

```
Range("C1:E36").Select
Selection. Format Conditions. Add Type:=xlExpression, Formulal:="=$D6=""Sun"""
Selection. Format Conditions (Selection. FormatConditions. Count).SetFirstPriority
with Selection. Format Conditions (1). Interior
.Pattern = xlLightVertical
. PatternColor = 65535
.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

I am trying to create a for loop that it should apply to all twelve sets - each with 3 columns (see image 2). Additionally, it should run 3 times - starting at rows `C6, C45,C84` - corresponding to the three year I am trying to display (see image 1). I am struggling with the for loop. And the relative abs reference on columns of `$D6` in the conditional formatting and how to make that be `$G6, $J6, $D84, $G84`.

```
For o = 1 TO 3 Step 1
    For I = 1 To 12 Step 1
    Range (.Cells(6, I * 3), .Cells (36, I * 3 + 2)).Select
    Selection. Format Conditions. Add Type:=xlExpressionFormulal:="=$D6=""Sun"""
    Selection. Format Conditions (Selection. Format Conditions. Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection. Format Conditions (1). Interior
   .Pattern = xlLightvertical
   .PatternColor = 65535
   .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
   .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Next I
Next o
End Sub'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No pictures of code. Please edit the post to include the code as text. For code formatting, use code fences \``` on seperate lines before and after the code block.

Comment: Does manually copying first three columns and pasting it three by three not worked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For copying formatting, I suggest `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` using `xlPasteFormats`. As for dynamically determining the ranges, since yours have a regular sizing and predictable location, its simplest to write a static `For Loop` to iterate the Row and Column numbers.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long 
    For r = 6 To 84 Step 39
        For c = 3 To 36 Step 3
            Cells(r, "C").Resize(38, 3).Copy
            Cells(r, c).Resize(38, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This code Copies formatting from "C6:E44" onto the adjacent columns. 12 Sets, each 3 columns wide (Eg "F6:H44","I6:K44"). Then it advances the row number from 6 to 45 and does it again, copying "C45:E83" onto "F45:H83" and the other 11 column sets. Then it advances from row 45 to row 84 and does this again.

In Response to your comments about applying a new/custom formatting for each range:

```vb
Sub Example()
    For r = 6 To 84 Step 39
        For c = 3 To 36 Step 3
            ApplyFormatting Cells(r, c).Resize(38, 3)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub ApplyFormatting(InRange As Range)
    InRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & InRange.Cells(1, 2).Address(False, True) & "=""Sun"""
    InRange.FormatConditions(InRange.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With InRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Pattern = xlLightVertical
        .PatternColor = 65535
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

This procedure `ApplyFormatting` takes each range and uses the address as part of a new formatting formula applied to the whole range.

Comment: That seems to work in the copy paste sense of it. But it still references the original set - because of the reference value of $D6. It's not dynamic.

Comment: @Nathan Fleischman: See my answer for how to make your conditional formatting so it will copy.

Comment: Please see my updated answer for how to apply a custom formula to each range.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a Sub that CF's a passed range as you wish.  Then call that as many times as you need, to set all columns

Setting the Conditional Formatting

```vb
Sub SetCF(r As Range)
    Dim rw As Long
    r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & r.Cells(1, 2).Address(False, True) & "=""Sun"""
    r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With r.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Pattern = xlLightVertical
        .PatternColor = 65535
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Calling it for a range

```
Sub Demo1()
    SetCF ActiveSheet.Range("C1:E36")
End Sub
```

Calling it for several offset ranges

```
Sub Demo2()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:E36")
    For i = 0 To 11
        SetCF r.Offset(, i * 3)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You beat me by less than a minute with this answer... Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to:

1. Create conditional formatting so it will copy both down and across
2. Copy and paste formatting to the other locations

To do 1)
Define conditional formatting **separately** for each cell C6, D6 and E6, using formula: `=OR(D6="Sat",D6="Sun")`.

You can now do 2):

1. Select cells C6:E6 and Copy
2. Select a target group (say) F6:H36 and Paste Formatting
3. Now Copy F6:H36 and Paste Formatting to each of the other column groups

Comment: That would highlight the center column only. I need it should highlight the entire row of the set. That's why I have it as $D6 and not D6.

Comment: Erm... no it won't. Re-read 'To do 1)'. The key is to define the condition in each cell (C6, then D6, then E6) **separately**, but using the same formula in each case.